# How to pass User object into json to send to api endpoint?

Tags: json, angular, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am getting this error 400 when trying to submit a POST.

```
        "$.User": [
            "The JSON value could not be converted to WebApi.Models.User. Path: $.User | LineNumber: 5 | BytePositionInLine: 19."
        ]
    }
```

This is my Order Model in asp.net core 3 api

```
namespace WebApi.Models
{
    public class DispatchRequest
    {
        [Key]
        public int DispatchRequestID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        public string DispatchRequestNo { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        public string CreatedOn { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "int(10)")]
        [ForeignKey("UserID")]
        public User User { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }

        
        public ICollection<DispatchRequestItem> DispatchRequestsItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So it seems like the problem is that the value for the json key "User" is not a user object. How do I do that, in order to make the POST request pass?

I am using angular to send the post request, but it didnt work, so I am using Postman now to try and troubleshoot and realized the above.

Answer (score 0):

As a general tip, I would first recommend you to start using Swagger, its a beautiful thing that makes you a page in apiURL/swagger where you can test all your endpoints and have examples of what object each endpoint needs. Also you can scaffold your angular api with the swagger.json and https://www.npmjs.com/package/api-client-generator

Why would you have as Required the object User? having the UserId as required would do just fine. Also if you are attaching the User object , you have to double check not to update the user in the db when EF Core does its magic

Comment: Yea I just realized it, and changed the required to the UserID instead. I managed to POST once, and I did something and it broke and now its returning error 500 System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.